# Is react 15.3.2 is compatible with react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I am trying to upgrade my project to react-routerv4, but while doing so I am getting following errors

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at new t (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at c._constructComponentWithoutOwner (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at c._constructComponent (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at c.mountComponent (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at Object.mountComponent (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at c.performInitialMount (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at c.mountComponent (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at Object.mountComponent (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at c.performInitialMount (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
    at c.mountComponent (vendor.2fdc9470.js:1)
```

I have written my ReactDOM.render like this

//index.js

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from "react-router-redux"
const store = configureStore({ app: { isMobile } }) 
const history = createHistory()
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        {routes}// these are the routes exported from routes.js
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  )
```

My routes are written like this //routes.js
    export default (
      
        
        
      
    )
This is exported and used in index.js file

Modules specific to the question have below mentioned versions.

```
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
 "react": "~15.3.2",
```

I know that I cannot use browserhostory.push in react router 4, that need to be replaced, but why i am seeing errors in vendor bundle. My vendor bundle consist of

```
vendor: [
      "react",
      "react-mdl",
      "react-router",
      "react-redux",
      "redux-form",
      "redux-saga",
      "redux-storage",
      "lodash",
      "moment",
    ],
```

I know that there is some problem in the history object that is being passed through the connectedrouter, but not able to solve it.Any help and pointer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your route.js file?

Comment: I will check your solution when I open my laptop tomorrow.route file content I have already mentioned in the code snippet above
. I have commented other part of code as if now.